# Asp .net webforms and the chrome back button

Tags: google-chrome, webforms

I have an application written in asp .net webforms.  I have disabled the ability of going back in the browser, since this is a web app and we don't want the users to hit the "back" button.  I've been working with the users regarding some big updates, and they have made it clear that they want to be able to hit the back button and not get a chrome error message.

In the application, I currently have set:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

I have commented all of this out.  Still chrome does not seem to like the back button.  I have explicitly set the .SetExpires to several minutes out in the future and I have set the Cacheability value to private.  Neither of these have helped so far.

So, how do I set the application, via either web.config settings or commands in the master page code behind, to allow chrome to show something from the application when the user hits the back button?

Comment: Just to add a bit more info into this.  The scenario I specifically have is page 1 loads and the search panel is displayed.  When the user hits the search button, page 1 is reload and the search results are displayed.  The users selects a link the search results, and page 2 is loaded with a detail screen where the user can edit information.  The problem is when the user hits the back button from page 2, the user expects the search results screen, and gets this chrome message.  The user expects to go back to the search results screen.

Comment: Just as an fyi, I found that if I eliminate the search results panel and instead create a search results screen, this seems to solve the problem.  That is probably the direction I will go.